# Flash CS4 Loader Class: Image Loads Initially, but Error Returned When Loading New Image

Tags: flash, image-loading, file-not-found

This is extremely difficult to explain in the title... First, here is my code in Actionscript:

```
var digitalGallery:Loader = new Loader();
digitalGallery.x = 730
digitalGallery.y = 210
digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/nair_evanescentautumn.png"));
addChild(digitalGallery);

function dgtlLatest(event:MouseEvent):void {
 if(event.target == new_thumb1) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/iilu_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
 else if(event.target == new_thumb2) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/daem_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
 else if(event.target == new_thumb3) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/moon_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
 else if(event.target == new_thumb4) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/dael_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
}

function dgtlGalery(event:MouseEvent):void {
 if(event.target == gal_thumb1) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/kryo_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
 else if(event.target == gal_thumb2) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/nair_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
 else if(event.target == gal_thumb3) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/lite_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
 else if(event.target == gal_thumb4) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/oasi_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
}

new_thumb1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dgtlLatest);
new_thumb2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dgtlLatest);
new_thumb3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dgtlLatest);
new_thumb4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dgtlLatest);

gal_thumb1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dgtlGalery);
gal_thumb2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dgtlGalery);
gal_thumb3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dgtlGalery);
gal_thumb4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dgtlGalery);
```

This script is for a loader image gallery in flash, as part of a class assignment. What happens is that in flash, when I open the swf file, the initial image (images/nair_evanescentautumn.png) will load fine. However, clicking on any thumbnail image (including the exact same images/nair_evanescentautumn.png), will result in an error saying the file cannot be found.

I cannot figure out why it is doing this... I've tested it over. Clicking each thumbnail does go to the correct position in the two separate functions. All said full-size image links are in the folder images/, and replacing the initial loader image will load the other images in place of the default one. However, clicking on any thumbnail still results in URL not found, even though everything works correctly.

This is just driving me crazy... it can't be this difficult to create a simple gallery.

The assignment is due Wednesday, though... I'm sure I can ask my instructor in-class, but I'd prefer to have it done before then, and I can't think of anything else to do except post this.

All help is greatly appreciated...

EDIT:

Sorry about not posting the error...

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

EDIT 2:

Here's a link to the entire set of files:

http://www.tsr-online.org/flash/index.swf

My server won't allow access to the /flash folder index, but I can give the directory listing.

/flash directory:
/images (contains all images)
/cmsn (contains commissions.swf subpages)
index.swf
home.swf
blog.swf
traditional.swf
digital.swf
photography.swf
commissions.swf

Before anyone asks why I'm putting this kind of content into a flash site, I'm not--this is only for a class assignment. I'm just trying to figure out why my images aren't loading right when I'm only doing the exact same thing in the functions as I am on the other pages.

Of note, commissions.swf has the exact same feature, just with swf files loaded instead, and it works perfectly fine. home, traditional, digital, and photography all have the image gallery, and all have the same issue (I only referenced one page because if I can fix one page I should be able to fix all of them).

As for the artworks, they are all my fiance's. The website design was built for her, and I used the website design for this project because I didn't want to have to build an entirely new interface design. Since the project also required a gallery, I felt that this interface would work just fine.

Comment: Can you post all of your project files somewhere? That would be the best case scenario because I could debug it in a jiffy for you that way, rather than guess weather theres anything I'm not seeing that might be the cause.

Comment: Also when posting these types of questions please paste in the exact error message that flash is giving you as well. Example "Error 1015: Blah blah blah MyClass line 51". If you don't see that much nfo make sure to go into your flash IDE publish settings and click the check box "enable debugging".

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the error... I added that to the first post, and here it is, too:

Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

I'll upload the files in question to a server and put a link in the first post. I'm going to have to do that tomorrow, anyway.

Comment: @JesseNicholson Alright, I added the error and a link to the flash application online in the first post. I also including a directory listing (my server won't allow the actual index to be displayed) and I included some additional details about the application in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spelling mistakes in your code. That's all the issue is. Example from your own code:

```
 else if(event.target == new_thumb2) {
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/daem_evanescantautumn.png"));
 }
```

When in fact the spelling is:

http://www.tsr-online.org/flash/images/daem_evanescentautumn.png

Note the exact issue is "vanesc *a* ntautumn.png" when it should be "vanesc *e* ntautumn.png."

Fix the spelling in your code above and all should be well.

Comment: Apparently my copy-pastes weren't working right, then... because I copied that initial "digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/nair_evanescentautumn.png"));" several times and replaced the second one with it just to make sure it was set correctly.

Ugh... <-<

I'll try this again and respond later. Thanks...

Comment: Meh... now I feel like an idiot. Although, evenescent does always give me issues.... :P Working now, thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. Don't feel like an idiot, this stuff happens to even the best. I've spent several hours banging my face off the table raging out over several pots of coffee on issues just like this so don't worry about it and don't let anyone try and make you feel stupid for it, just keep pressin on. :)

Comment: Heh, thanks a lot... That helps. ^_^

I'm sure to post more questions here in the future when (not if) I run into other problems. xD

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot make a comment on your post because of the strange restrictions I have to write an answer (which is a question to you): Why do you try to load the same image twice?

Comment: Loading the same image twice is irrelevant, he shouldn't be getting an error of the nature he describes over loading the same asset two or more times.

Comment: Of course, but loading it twice is unnecessary and removing such things first might even solve the problem or lead to an understanding of why it occurs. Anyway some more information about the error would be nice.

Comment: Its not really loading the same image twice. The loader is -supposed- to remove whatever is in it and then load something new. Its supposed to be a gallery; one image appears by default, then you can click a thumbnail and the image is replaced by a new one. Then if you click the thumbnail of the original image it reloads that one, as well.

And I have tried switching the code from reloading the first image to reloading the current frame... it still doesn't solve the issue of why the other images aren't loading.

Answer (score 0):

You're kinda going about it in a really roundabout sort of way anyway - try this out:

```
var digitalGallery:Loader;

var thumbs:Array = ['new_thumb1',
                'new_thumb2',
                'new_thumb3',
                'new_thumb4',
                'gal_thumb1',
                'gal_thumb2',
                'gal_thumb3',
                'gal_thumb4']

var images:Array = ['iilu_evanescantautumn',
                'daem_evanescantautumn',
                'moon_evanescantautumn',
                'dael_evanescantautumn',
                'kryo_evanescantautumn',
                'nair_evanescantautumn',
                'lite_evanescantautumn',
                'oasi_evanescantautumn']

setupThumbs()

function setupThumbs(){
    for (var i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++){
        var thumb = this.getChildByName(thumbs[i])
        thumb.id = i
        thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadImage);
    }
}

function loadImage(event:MouseEvent){
    var id = event.currentTarget.id
    digitalGallery = new Loader();
    digitalGallery.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
    digitalGallery.load(new URLRequest("images/"+images[id]+".png"));
}

function loadComplete(event:Event):void {
    trace("Complete");
    addChild(digitalGallery)
    digitalGallery.x = 730;
    digitalGallery.y = 210;
}
```

Comment: I suppose I could've done something like that... but I'm not too keen on ActionScript yet. Not that I'm bad at programming--I find it far easier than the design aspect. The way I set it up is (one of) the methods I was told to set it up in. Unfortunately, the other method I was told to use by my instructor didn't work, either...